# Jenkins Batch contains .exe command inside

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job that runs an "Execute Windows batch command", inside that batch I have a.exe, Jenkins job fails with this message:

> "a.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command"

but when I run manually  batch that have inside **a.exe** is working.

Comment: "X is not recognized as an internal or external command" usually means that your executable "X" not found. How do you call `a.exe` ? Where is it located ?

Comment: I have a **Build.bat** that has inside **a.exe**, **b.exe**, **c.exe** ... When I run manually **Build.bat** or from cmd is working, but when I call **Build.bat** from Jenkins, I receive "a.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command", "b.exe is not recognized as an internal or external" command", "c.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Windows Exe Runner Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+Exe+Runner+Plugin), I have been using it for a while and it let me run `.exe` from jenkins.

Comment: Yes is working, but I have more then one .exe, like this: **call NuGet.exe restore a.sln** , 

**call NuGet.exe restore b.sln**  ...